# django serialization on natural key error

Tags: python, django

I have a django model where i use natural keys:

```
class AcademicProgramsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, acad_program_id, program_title, required_credits):
        return self.get(acad_program_id = acad_program_id, program_title = program_title, required_credits = required_credits)

class AcademicPrograms(models.Model):

    objects = AcademicProgramsManager()
    acad_program_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    acad_program_category = models.ForeignKey(AcademicProgramCategories)
    acad_program_type = models.ForeignKey(AcademicProgramTypes)
    acad_program_code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    program_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    required_credits = models.IntegerField()
    min_gpa = models.FloatField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def natural_key(self):
    return (self.acad_program_id, self.program_title, self.required_credits)

class StudentAcademicPrograms(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    academic_program = models.ForeignKey(AcademicPrograms)
    credits_completed = models.IntegerField()
    academic_program_gpa = models.FloatField()
    primary_program = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
    return self.credits_completed
```

When i am trying to serialize the `StudentAcademicPrograms` with the following command, it is throwing an error.

```
>>> with open("datafile.json","w") as out:...     
        serialize("json", StudentAcademicPrograms.objects.all(), indent=2, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)
    ... 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
      File "/home/abhishek/projects/texascompletes/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 122, in serialize
        s.serialize(queryset, **options)
      File "/home/abhishek/projects/texascompletes/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 58, in serialize
        self.end_object(obj)
      File "/home/abhishek/projects/texascompletes/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 52, in end_object
        cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, **self.json_kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 186, in dump
        default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).iterencode(obj)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_natural_foreign_keys'
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys), `use_natural_keys` was "splitted" to `use_natural_foreign_keys` and `use_natural_primary_keys` in Django 1.7 version which is not a stable version currently.

You can either [upgrade to django development version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-development-version) or use `use_natural_keys` keyword.

Comment: hmm.. i was looking at the documentation for the developing version.